# 1, 4, 7 numeric collection

Tags: sequences-and-series

Curious lay person here; my first post.

**Background:**

Years ago I was introduced to a numeric collection (sequence?) involving the numbers 1, 4, 7, and possibly beyond.  These numbers were used to control user access to computer files in the Primos operating system.  Users were allowed to either a) read a file, b) write to a file,  including creating a file, and c) executing the file. Read, write, and execute were represented by the numbers 1, 4, 7, respectively.  For example, if a user was assigned the ability to only read a file, the number 1 was assigned.  If the user could read and execute the file, the number 8 (1+7) was assigned.

As I recall, 1, 4, and 7 were used because no matter which read, write, execute status was assigned, the resulting 1-, 2-, or 3-way sum would be unique.

**Question:**

I'm trying to confirm that my memory is correct; does such a numeric pattern, where the sum of any combination of numbers in the (set?) results in a unique result, and if so, is there a generic term for such a pattern?  I spent a half-hour on searching the internet with no success.

Comment: [This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) may be what you seek.

Comment: **If** the comment of @JohnDouma is on point, see also [this section of Wikipedia Unix File Permissions Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Numeric_notation),

Comment: In general, taking for such a collection the first $k$ powers of $2$ is an optimal choice – no two sums are the same, and the sum of values is the smallest possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general type of thing is called a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) or a set of [flags](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute).

Each flag has a value that's a power of 2, so that in the [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) representation of the number, each flag corresponds to a single bit, independent of the others.

[Unix file permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm) are a particular convention of a bit field defined as a combination of Read=4, Write=2, and Execute=1.  This allows 8 possible combinations of permissions:

- 0 = no permission
- 1 = Execute
- 2 = Write
- 3 = Write + Execute
- 4 = Read
- 5 = Read + Execute
- 6 = Read + Write
- 7 = Read + Write + Execute

Each 3-bit combination can be expressed as one [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) digit.